# Add h2 within .entry-content under h1 genesis

Tags: php, html, wordpress, genesis

I am trying to add an h2 under the h1 within the .entry-content div on the genesis framework.

I would like the code to output the following:

```
<header class="entry-header">
   <h1 itemprop="headline" class="entry-title">Page Header Title</h1>
   <h2>Page Sub Header Title</h2> 
</header>
```

I believe I need an action hook of some kind but I'm not 100% sure to begin.

My next thought is how would I add the h2 content for each page? As each page will need to have a different h2. Will I need to create a custom field or call the h2's conditionally onto each page?

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks, 
William

Comment: You can create a custom field via ACF and set it to pages or post or any post type of your choice. and get it printed on the pages

Comment: Thanks for the input about custom fields, however this still dose not solve my main issues of adding an h2 tag into the .entry-header.

Comment: Do you want a script that adds automatically a <h2> tag inside the .entry-header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to use the *genesis_entry_header* action. So, you could add the following to your functions.php to get a sub title

```
add_action('genesis_entry_header', 'handle_event_sub_title');
function handle_event_sub_title(){
    global $post;
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'sub_title')?sprintf('<h2>%s</h2>',get_post_meta($post->ID,'sub_title')):'';
}
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thanks for the hook. How can I apply this to multiple pages with a different h2 content on each page? Should I use a conditional page statement or would some sort of custom field be better? Thanks

Comment: William, you could add a Custom Field on each page called sub_title -  and then in the code you could do something like the edit I've made to the code above